# How to use Sublime text editor to resolve git merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, sublimetext2, conflict

I have installed "Submerge", but it can only care to revision. Git already changed to file to "need to merge" status. I know there are other tools can do that, but I am just wondering if I can do this just using Sublime, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding how to use Sublimerge:

I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but I'm getting closer.

First, you need a handy path to the Sublime binary:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Then, in your git GUI or git command line, configure ~/bin/subl as your merge tool.

I use Source Tree, and I haven't figured exactly how to best use Sublimerge, but I managed to open both versions, merge them, and then I have to do a bit of manual work.

Still not smooth, but better than nothing!

Comment: Do you managed to open both versions in sulblimerge or in standard sublime splitted window ?

Comment: @svassr I stopped doing this as it was a mess. I don't remember, I think it was standard sublime splitted window, with some functionality of sublimerge floating around.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [Sublimerge](http://www.sublimerge.com/) that could fit your needs.

Comment: I already installed it, not sure how to use it.